# jquery datatables reset aaSorting is giving me errors or not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am trying to do a custom multisort UI to sort a jquery datable so the user doesn't need to hold down shift key. I try to reset the sorting by settings aaSorting = [] or using fnSortNeutral() and it gives error. Any ideas??

**"oSettings.fnSortNeutral is not a function"**

Here is my code, I am using latest 1.94 from CDN..

```
var oSettings = $('#' + tableId).dataTable({ "bRetrieve": true });

try
{
    oSettings.fnSortNeutral();
}
catch (e) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(e.message));
}
```

Comment: I'm having some trouble with the DataTables reference (for one, the main function `dataTable()` is not in the reference in a logical place...) but there isn't a `fnSortNeutral()` isn't in the reference. Are you sure it should be a function?

Comment: I even tried this for a test too to see if I could manually set 2nd and 3rd columns to multi sort and it completes without error but doesn't do anything?? var oSettings = $('#' + tableId).dataTable({ "bRetrieve": true }).fnSettings();
try
{
oSettings.aaSorting = [ [ 1, "asc", 0 ], [ 2, "asc", 0 ] ];
}
catch (e) {
alert(JSON.stringify(e.message));
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using `$('#' + tableId).dataTable({ "bRetrieve": true }).fnSort([]);` ?

Comment: I figured it out on my own eventually before this. But I will give you the points.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that fnSortNeutral should be defined by yourself to use it.
So first define it something like this:

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.oApi.fnSortNeutral = function ( oSettings )
{
/* Remove any current sorting by adding for example default sorting or leave it empty */
oSettings.aaSorting = [[ 1, "desc" ]];
/* Redraw */
oSettings.oApi._fnReDraw( oSettings );
};
```

Then you can use it:

```
oTable.fnSortNeutral();
```

Answer (score 0):

U can use aDatasort feature, it will me more efficient.

http://datatables.net/docs/DataTables/1.9.beta.1/DataTable.defaults.columns.html#aDataSort_details

Comment: Why is it more efficient? And also what are targets?